R - RiskPortfolios's package - Optimal portfolio ERROR
I'm trying to determine the optimal weights, but the 'riskeff' type doesn't work.
TYPE in the optimalPortfolio function has several asset allocation strategies. I want to use the 'riskeff' type to determine the asset allocation weights. However, I am getting an error in the riskeff type while the other types are calculating fine.
packages <- c('quantmod', 'ggplot2', 'tidyverse', 'psych', 'PerformanceAnalytics', 'magrittr', 'timeSeries', 'RiskPortfolios')
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)

# 1. return data ------------------------------------------------------

# ticker <- c('SPY', 'IWM', 'EFA', 'TLT')
ticker <- c('SPY', 'TLT')
portfolio_n <- length(ticker)
getSymbols(ticker)
prices <- do.call(cbind,
                  lapply(ticker, function(x) Ad(get(x)))) %>% 
  setNames(ticker)
rets <- Return.calculate(prices) %>% na.omit(.)
head(rets)

# cov-var matrix
covmat <- covEstimation(rets)
semiDev <- semidevEstimation(rets)

# 2. Optimal weights ---------------------------------------------------
opt_w <- optimalPortfolio(Sigma = covmat, semiDev = semiDev,
                          control = list(type = 'riskeff',
                                         constraint = 'lo')) %>% 
  round(., 4) %>% 
  setNames(colnames(rets)) %>% 
  print(.)

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, pos, i - 1, value = 1) : subscript out of bounds

In the optimalPortfolio function in #2, I get the same error as above. I think the problem is in the 'semiDev' part, but I don't know how to fix it, please help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you don't get an answer here, you might want to ask at R-SIG-Finance as well ( https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance ). If you suspect it to be a bug, you should contact the maintainer (in R, type maintainer("RiskPortfolios")) directly.
